# Validation Error on img tag: Bad value for attribute src on element img: Backslash ("\") used as path segment delimiter

Tags: html

```
       <div class="logo">
           <img src="assets\images\main-logo\logo.jpg" alt="logo">
       </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have validate this code in validate.w3.org ang get error like:

> Bad value assets\images\main-logo\logo.jpg for attribute src on
>   element img: Backslash ("\") used as path segment delimiter.  From
>   line 43, column 42; to line 43, column 96  ss="logo">

Comment: Show us the code!

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear: use `/` instead of `\\` as path segment delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

So simple :

```
<div>
  <a>
    <div class="logo">
       <img src="assets/images/main-logo/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```